# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT CONS_REF|BILL_MT...@691:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41222188)

Tags: android, web-services, http, ksoap

I have developed an android application through which I am downloading data in textfile from website using .net webservice. Now, since my data contains only 690 rows so reaching row 691 it is giving Unexpected token, so please tell me how should I apply a check to skip blank rows...The code I am placing below as well as Logcat

```
   public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String name, String webMethName) {
    String resTxt = null;
    // Create request

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Name
    celsiusPI.setName("name");
    // Set Value
    celsiusPI.setValue(name);
    // Set dataType
    celsiusPI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    //request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
    request.addProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to fahren static variable
        resTxt = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resTxt = "Error occured";
    } 

    return resTxt;
}
```

Log cat

```
          12-31 09:59:48.233: W/System.err(2856):
          org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT 
          CONS_REF|BILL_MT...@691:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41222188)
          12-31 09:59:48.293: W/System.err(2856):   at     
          org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:426)
          12-31 09:59:48.453: W/System.err(2856):   at    
          org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
          12-31 09:59:48.483: W/System.err(2856):   at   
          org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2029)
          12-31 09:59:48.503: W/System.err(2856):   at  
          org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)]
          12-31 09:59:48.523: W/System.err(2856):   at 
          org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
          12-31 09:59:48.653: W/System.err(2856):   at 
          org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
          12-31 09:59:48.693: W/System.err(2856):   at 
          com.prgguru.android.WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(WebService.java:48)
          12-31 09:59:48.723: W/System.err(2856):   at
```

Comment: show your line number 691

Comment: @QuokMoon Line 691 is blank

Comment: check null value before inserting

Comment: @QuokMoon Is that possible to apply a check for null value at client side

Comment: its possible both side... paste your response here http://pastie.org/

Comment: @QuokMoon please check it at http://pastie.org/8589012

Comment: come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab

Comment: same problem Here is my err Trace.
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT Unauthorized: Ac...@1:58 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41ce21e0) 
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:426)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2029)
at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:275)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this problem alot and finally solved it.
This problem is not for android coding, It is for .Net Service Binding.

In .Net web service on the server I changed service model to code below and it worked:

Old :

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basich" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
```

New :

```
<basicHttpBinding>

     <binding name="basich">
    </binding>      
  </basicHttpBinding>
```